# I have created the huffman tree but im having issues in generating the codes out ouf it

Tags: java, huffman-code

**Here is my function, i seed it with the root node of my tree and a character to be found inside the tree. It successfully returns me the alphabet to be searched but it does not give me the path to the element. Im a bit stuck any help would be appriciated**

public Node traversingTree(Node root,String charToFind){

```
    Node tempRoot = root;

    if (root != null){

        if (charToFind.equals(root.getAlphabet()))
        {
            //Another Point of consideration
            System.out.print(root.getAlphabet());
            System.out.println(": "+pathCodes);
            pathCodes.clear();
            return root;
        }
        Node result;

        if ((result = traversingTree(root.leftChild, charToFind)) != null){

            pathCodes.add("0");
            return result;

        }else
            pathCodes.add("1");
            return traversingTree(root.rightChild, charToFind); 
        }

        }
    pathCodes.clear();

     return null;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly what you *do* get, but looking at your code, your right-hand recursion is adding the '1' *before* continuing down to look for the appropriate node. However you *clear* the code at the leaf node, which will occur after all the '1's have been added. So I'd expect your code to only contain '0's, as the '0's are appended *after* recursing.

Also I suspect that as you are adding the chars on the way back *up* the tree, the codes will be back to front.

While rethinking your recursion, I would recommend *not* using the huffman tree like this anyway. Searching for the codes is quite inefficient - I would suggest traversing the tree once, building a table of alphabet+code, and then simply indexing into that.

Preferably, use the tree only to calculate the code lengths, and generate the codes using a canonical encoding.